# How can I load a json file from location defined in an environmental variable in SvelteKit?

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, vite, sveltekit

We are using AWS Code Pipeline to deploy a CDK and SvelteKit app. The first CodeBuild instance builds the backend CDK app and then returns a json artefact which contains all of the api endpoints. I then feed this artefact to the second code build instance so that it can build the SvelteKit app with the newest endpoints embedded.

The problem is that the way AWS Code Build mounts this file is by putting it somewhere in the file system and then setting an environmental variable to tell me where it is. This means the TS code to import this needs to use an environmental variable in a import statement like this:

```
import { CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_DARA_STORE_ARTIFACT } from "$env/static/private";
import JSONFile from CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR_DARA_STORE_ARTIFACT;
```

This trows an error saying:

```
String literal expected
```

How can I achieve this in such a way that it reads the ENV variable, loads the json at the contained path and then bundles the json data with my code?